# i am trying to select hidden dropdown menu option using selenium webdriver python but it throw "Message: no such element: Unable to locate element"

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, implicitwait

i trying this code

```
import requests as req
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
#from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
#from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
#from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select as select
driver = webdriver.Chrome(f'F:\Deep Learning\chromedriver')
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://www.naukri.com/')
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//input[@placeholder="Enter skills / designations / companies"]').send_keys('data scientist')
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//input[@placeholder="Enter location"]').send_keys('pune,Delhi NCR,Hydrabad')
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,".dropdownMainContainer").click
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

#driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="expereinceDD"]').click
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//span[normalize-space()='2 years']").click
driver.quit()
```

but it throw error massege

before click on the "select experiance" it show!
[select experiance screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyqGN.jpg)
[before clicking on"select experiance"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CY0YV.jpg)
after click on the "select experiance" dropdown menu its show
[after click on it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WwAs.jpg)

error massage is "Message: no such element: Unable to locate element"
for reference i given the link https://www.naukri.com/
[error massege](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qb5J.jpg)

how can i click that "select experiance" menu so to select one of the option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine, if you use `click()` instead of `click`.

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,".dropdownMainContainer").click()


driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//span[normalize-space()='2 years']").click()
```

Also, use `explicit wait` instead of `implicit wait`. By `Explicit wait`, I mean `WebdriverWait`. It helps with good practice.

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem here is that you trying to use non-existing `.click` method instead of *Selenium* `.click()` method.
Also, no need to define `driver.implicitly_wait(10)` several times. This command sets the implicitly wait for the `driver` for the entire session.
This code works:

```py
import requests as req
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
#from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
#from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
#from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select as select
driver = webdriver.Chrome(f'F:\Deep Learning\chromedriver')
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://www.naukri.com/')
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//input[@placeholder="Enter skills / designations / companies"]').send_keys('data scientist')
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//input[@placeholder="Enter location"]').send_keys('pune,Delhi NCR,Hydrabad')
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,".dropdownMainContainer").click()
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//span[normalize-space()='2 years']").click()
driver.quit()
```